# masm assembly how to divide and multiply numbers using the fpu

Tags: winforms, math, assembly, masm, fpu

I am new to masm and assembly and need some help. I have spent probably 6 hours on this already. I have 3 text boxes and 2 buttons. I want one of the buttons to multiply the numbers in the  text boxes and show the result in the third text box, and the other button to divide the numbers in the 2 text boxes and show the result in the third text box. the numbers are almost always going to have decimals in them.

I have tried a lot of things but this is the code I think is the closest.

divide

```
invoke GetDlgItemInt,hWin,textbox1,NULL,TRUE
mov esi,eax
invoke GetDlgItemInt,hWin,textbox2,NULL,TRUE
mov edi,eax 

mov math1,esi

fild math1

mov math2,edi

fidiv math2

fstsw math3

invoke SetDlgItemInt,hWin,textbox3,math3,TRUE
```

multiply

```
invoke GetDlgItemInt,hWin,textbox1,NULL,TRUE
mov esi,eax
invoke GetDlgItemInt,hWin,textbox2,NULL,TRUE
mov edi,eax 

mov math1,esi

fild math1

mov math2,edi

fimul math2

fstsw math3

invoke SetDlgItemInt,hWin,textbox3,math3,TRUE
```

.data

```
math1   dd   ?
math2   dd   ?
math3   dw   ?
```

the code above gives the wrong numbers in the text box. can someone please show me what I need to do.

thank you

**Update**

this code works

```
LOCAL var1 :QWORD
LOCAL var2 :QWORD
LOCAL var3 :QWORD
LOCAL str1[19]:BYTE
LOCAL str2[19]:BYTE
LOCAL str3[19]:BYTE

invoke GetDlgItemText,hWin,textbox1,addr str1,9
invoke StrToFloat,addr str1,addr var1

invoke GetDlgItemText,hWin,textbox2,addr str2,9
invoke StrToFloat,addr str2,addr var2

finit
fld var1
fld var2
fdiv
fstp var3

invoke FloatToStr,var3,addr str3
invoke SetDlgItemText,hWin,textbox3,addr str3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FSTSW` is storing the status word, not the result. What you need is `FISTP` (for integers) or `FSTP` (for floating point).

Comment: I tried to use those 2 but they did not work I just got the integer not the decimal. do I need to convert the text to floating point numbers or something before I do the calculations

Comment: Yes, you have to convert to floating point and back. The updated code looks like it should indeed work, use a debugger to see why it doesn't.

Comment: on the edit code when I type 4.2 * 2 it gives me 17.64 and when I change the fmul to fdiv it always gives 1 no matter the numbers

Comment: I tried this variation of the edit code invoke SendMessage,hWin,WM_GETTEXT,ResultlengthYpixelstextbox,addr str1
invoke StrToFloat,addr str1,addr var1
invoke SendMessage,hWin,WM_GETTEXT,ResultlengthYpixelstextbox,addr str2
invoke StrToFloat,addr str2,addr var2


finit
fld  var1
fld  var2
fmul
fstp var3

invoke FloatToStr,var3,addr str3
invoke SetDlgItemText,hWin,unitofmeasurementtextbox,addr str3
and it gives me 0 every time

Comment: I am not sure what I was doing wrong before but your right the code does work thanks.